# How to make a time control readonly using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am working on a certain ui and i have heard complains from the users that they are able to type in the time controls other numbers like 22323234 and save which is in need not a valid time.
this is how i make my time control for both 12hr and 24hr systems

```
 var table_html = '<td style="min-width: 200px;"><input name="' + control_id + '" id="' + control_id + '" value="' + row_val + '" type="time" datetime="h:mm"></td>';

 var table_html = '<td style="min-width: 200px;"><input name="' + control_id + '" id="' + control_id + '" value="' + row_val + '" type="time" datetime="hh:mm"></td>';
```

i have tried to include the readonly property in both and i was still able to enter values in these controls.
Any idea on how i will make them readonly will be highly appreciated

regards,

Jose

Answer (score 1):

html code

```
<td style="min-width: 200px;"><input name="1" id="2" value="12345" type="time" datetime="h:mm"></input></td>

<td style="min-width: 200px;"><input name="1" id="2" value="3" type="time" datetime="hh:mm"></input></td>
<br/>
<p>disabled input</p>
<!-- to disable -->
<td style="min-width: 200px;"><input name="1" id="2" value="12345" type="time" datetime="h:mm" disabled></input></td>

<td style="min-width: 200px;"><input name="1" id="2" value="3" type="time" datetime="hh:mm" disabled></input></td>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/33sDR/

Comment: thanks guys...i was making a small mistake with i have sorted it out. all your solutions given above are correct.cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can try as below

```
$("#TIMEControlID").attr("disabled", true);
```